# Get highest number from two-dimensional arrays

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I need the highest number from ***rate*** in a two-dimensional array

```
print_r($taxes = $tax->get_rates($product->get_tax_class()));

//output
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [rate] => 9
            [label] => BTW 9%
            [shipping] => yes
            [compound] => no
        )

)
Array
(
    [4] => Array
        (
            [rate] => 21
            [label] => BTW 21%
            [shipping] => yes
            [compound] => no
        )

)
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [rate] => 9
            [label] => BTW 9%
            [shipping] => yes
            [compound] => no
        )

)
```

I can use the max function in PHP. For using this function I need one array with all rates like

```
Array
(
    '9',
    '21,
    '9'
);
```

I tried something but the result is not good at all

```
$taxes = $tax->get_rates($product->get_tax_class());
foreach($taxes as $tax){
    $vat = array($tax['rate']);
}
print_r($vat);
//output
Array
(
    [0] => 9
)
Array
(
    [0] => 21
)
Array
(
    [0] => 9
)
```

Who can help me a little bit further?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I don't see how you're getting the output you show at the end. That would happen if the `print_r()` call were inside the `foreach` loop.

Comment: `$vat = array_column($taxes, 'rate');`

Comment: What you probably wanted was `$vat[] = $tax['rate'];` This is basic syntax for pushing onto an array.

Answer (score 1):

Solved

```
$taxes = $tax->get_rates($product->get_tax_class());
foreach($taxes as $tax){
    $vat[] = $tax['rate'];
}

print_r(max($vat));
```